# Laravel Seeder stuck forever

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to seed my database with 40,000 records for a table. But the seeder takes forever and no progress is seen in database. Any idea on how to speed this process.

```
 public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);

        factory(\App\Model\Workflow::class, 10)->create();
        factory(\App\Model\WorkflowStage::class, 100)->create();
        factory(\App\Model\PartnerCategory::class, 10)->create();



        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguard();
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::beginTransaction();

        factory(\App\Model\Partner::class, 40000)->create()->each(function ($partner) {

            $partner->contact()->save(factory(\App\Model\PartnerContact::class)->make());
            $partner->address()->save(factory(\App\Model\PartnerAddress::class)->make());
            $partner->contract()->save(factory(\App\Model\PartnerContract::class)->make());

        });

        factory(\App\Model\PartnerBranch::class, 1000)->create();
        factory(\App\Model\Product::class, 1000)->create();

        factory(\App\Model\Client::class, 20000)->create()->each(function ($client) {
            $client->contact()->save(factory(\App\Model\Contact::class)->make());
            $client->contact()->save(factory(\App\Model\Address::class)->make());
            $client->contact()->save(factory(\App\Model\Education::class)->make());
            $client->contact()->save(factory(\App\Model\Visa::class)->make());
        });

        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::commit();
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::reguard();

    }
```

My seeder code in DatabaseSeeder is as above.

Comment: That's way more than 40000, you have over 200,000 records being inserted...

Comment: So there is no way to insert that amount of data?

Comment: There definitely is, but it seems excessive.  It's going to take a very long time and you have it all in a single transaction...

Comment: What are you doing to verify that no progress is seen in the database?  It doesn't even create the 10 workflow objects or it stalls later on?

Comment: how are you inserting 40000 data, is it from some other source ? you should try bulk insert

Comment: it creates 10,100 and 1000 records but when i seed 40000 records I can't see any records being inserted

Comment: @sumit I am using faker

Comment: @Bikram because the records don't exist until you commit the transaction, read up on transactions.

Comment: @Devon You are right. The process completed just now and can see all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having all of this in a single transaction will speed up the execution, but it will also make it so these records won't exist, or at least aren't persisted until that transaction is actually committed.   Since you are creating over 200,000 fake records and running over 200,000 insert queries to the database, this will take some time to run.

Having this much data in a single seeder seems excessive to me.  You could always create a separate seeder to create a few thousand Partner records and run it multiple times wherever you seem to need this much data seeded.  I just can't imagine having a need for this many records in all environments or for developers trying to seed their local database.

Comment: I am trying to test the my application with large dataset.